# DAX How to get the average of the values shown in a matrix?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a measure as follows which essentially inserts a value of 0.8 in the row for timeframe 14:00-15:00:

```
ProjectedRate =
IF(
DATEDIFF(SELECTEDVALUE('Time'[Timeframe from]),[ThisHour],HOUR) >= 0,
[ObservedRate],
0.8
)
```

When I put it in a matrix table, I get the following result:

| Timeframe | ProjectedRate | ObservedRate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7:00:00-8:00:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 8:00:00-9:00:00 | .7059 | .7059 |
| 9:00:00-10:00:00 | .5882 | .5882 |
| 10:00:00-11:00:00 | .2273 | .2273 |
| 11:00:00-12:00:00 | .1765 | .1765 |
| 12:00:00-13:00:00 | .1905 | .1905 |
| 13:00:00-14:00:00 | .25 | .25 |
| 14:00:00-15:00:00 | .8 |  |
| Total | .4112 | .4112 |

SELECTEDVALUE('Time'[Start from]) contains the value of the start of the timeframe (14:00:00 from 14:00:00-15:00:00)

[This Hour] is 14:00:00

As you can see, the total row is returning the wrong result. It is showing only the average of the [ObservedRate] measure which itself is a simple division between two columns. (14:00:00-15:00:00 is blank)

How can I get the Total row to show the correct average of the values in the table ?

Expected total should be .4923 (49%) ((1 + .7059 + .5882 + .2273 + .1765 + .1905 + .25 + .8) / 8)

Comment: How can I know what the correct values are without some sample data?

Comment: The values are correct. The only error is the value of the total in ProjectedComplianceRate. You can sum the rows of each column to verify. I'm not sure what more data you're looking for?

Comment: Why did you delete the last question you posted? If I answer this one, will you delete it too?

Comment: No. The last question was deleted because the response provided was identical to the formula in the question so clearly it needed to be reworked and until I can, it wasn't worth leading people down the wrong path.

Comment: @Pieter I added a link to the test file which contains sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your measure to:

```
ProjectedComplianceRate =
AVERAGEX (
    VALUES ( 'Hour Chart'[Time Buckets] ),
    CALCULATE (
        IF (
            DATEDIFF (
                SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Hour Chart'[Timeframe from] ),
                [MaxObservedHour],
                HOUR
            ) >= 0,
            [ObservedComplianceRate],
            0.8
        )
    )
)
```

Result:

[image]

Please note that the average total is different from the number in your question (please check your calculations, there seems to be a mistake).

Why your formula didn't work:
Think what happens in the total. SELECTEDVALUE function only works if the column contains one value; if multiple values are provided, it returns a blank (or an alternative value). In the total, all time buckets are visible, so SELECTEDVALUE always returns a blank, and your IF condition is always negative. As a result, in the total's calculation 0.8 never shows up.

To fix this, you need to provide "row context" in the total. Use VALUE function to list all time buckets, then use AVERAGX function to iterate over the list. CALCULATE function is needed for "context transition" - to "tell" the iterator which specific row it's on. After the ProjectedComplianceRate is calculated for each row, the results are averaged, giving the correct total.